# How can I write a program that prints a multiplication table of size m by n which is provided by the user in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Examples:

```
m n: 2 3
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
m n: 4 2
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
4 * 1 = 4
4 * 2 = 8
```

I have written this code but i said "list assignment index out of range", how can I fix it? thanks

```
m, n = input('m n: ').split()
x = []
for i in range(0, int(m)):
    for j in range(0, int(n)):
        x[j] = int(m[i]) * int(n[j])
    print(str(i) + ' * ' + str(j) + ' = ',x[j])
```

Comment: maybe you can look this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: what is `m[i]` & `n[j]` here in `x[j] = int(m[i]) * int(n[j])` this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m, n = input('m n: ').split()

for i in range(1, int(m)+1):
    for j in range(1, int(n)+1):
        print(str(i) + ' * ' + str(j) + ' = ', i * j)
```